# Map typescript Enum to typescript Record properties missing from type

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, enums, record

I've been trying to map an enum similar to this to a typescript record.

```
enum Fruits {
    Banana,
    Apple,
    Orange
}
```

Then I have this interface

```
interface IFruitState {
    isRotten: boolean
}
```

I created this type

```
type FuitRecord<TFruit extends number, TFruitState> = Record<TFruit, TFruitState>;
```

And finally I wanted to map the enum into a Record. This makes sense because at this point I need to set the same object for all enums, so I tried something like this

```
const fruits: FuitRecord<Fruits, IFruitState> = Object
    .keys(Fruits)
    .map(key) => ({ [key]: { isRotten: false } as IFruitState }));
```

It will throw this error

```
Type '{ [x: number]: IFruitState; }[]' is missing the following properties from type 'FuitRecord<Fruits, IFruitState>': 0, 1, 2
```

This is my workaround, but I really wanted to avoid doing it this way

```
const fruits: FuitRecord<Fruits, IFruitState> = {
    [Fruits.Apple]: { isRotten: false },
    [Fruits.Banana]: { isRotten: false },
    [Fruits.Orange]: { isRotten: false }
};
```

Anyone has a better idea?

Comment: `map` will produce an array.. not a single object. Do you want to produce an object ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir yes, I want to create a record where the keys would be the enums